# Does bounded Zermelo construct any cumulative hierarchy?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axioms

ZF is sufficient to construct the von Neumann hierarchy, and prove that every set appears at some stage $V_\alpha$. This is the basis for Scott's trick, for instance. But how much of ZF is needed? Is bounded Zermelo/Mac Lane set theory enough, no Choice assumed? I know Foundation is necessary, and I'm not getting rid of that. I've seen something called the "rank axiom" in discussion of second-order version of original Zermelo ([these notes](http://math.boisestate.edu/%7Eholmes/hierarchy.pdf)), but I'm sure people have finely calibrated what precisely is needed.

To be honest, all I really want is an ordinal-valued rank function such that sets of rank at most $\alpha$ form a set, for all $\alpha$, and all sets have a rank. So if the von Neumann hierarchy doesn't work, I'm happy to work with something else (and for 'ordinals', I don't *need* von Neumann ordinals).

Comment: You need some Replacement, at least in the von Neumann case. If you are willing to work with "Fregean ordinals", there might be a way to resolve this without too much Replacement.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In fact it requires considerable amount of Replacement. In particular even $(\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathsf{Replacement})+\Delta_0\text{-}\mathsf{Replacement}$ couldn't prove that for every ordinal $\alpha$ there is $V_\alpha$, i.e. the set of all elements of the rank $\alpha$. This is because $H\aleph_\omega$ (the set of all sets $x$ s.t. the transitive closure of $x$ is of the cardinality $<\aleph_\omega$) is a model of  this theory.

Comment: @Fedor: If you read closely, I was referring to the remark at the end of the question, foregoing the von Neumann hierarchy **and** the von Neumann ordinals.

Comment: David, you can't get rid of the von Neumann part too easily: let $\alpha$ be the supremum of the von Neumann ordinals of the model, you might want to "pace yourself" with adding those to the levels of your hierarchy. But that means that the cofinality of your hierarchy must be the same as the cofinality of $\alpha$. Taking Mathias' $M_\lambda$ example of a model of Zermelo shows that this is impossible (as the rank function must be unbounded in all possible order types, i.e. the real Ord, but $\alpha=\lambda$ is a set).

Comment: @Asaf I was commenting on the first sentence of your reply that were about the case of von Neumann ordinals.

Comment: Hmm, so what do you two think is then the answer? I worry about some circularity if one tries to define the ordinals using a Scott-type trick, but then a hierarchy index by these ordinals.

Comment: @David I think that it is essential to have $\Pi_1$-Replacement, PowerSet, and Regularity as axioms. I don't think that the usage of some alternative presentation of ordinals would really help. Note that in the model $H\aleph_\omega$ for ranks $\alpha\ge\omega2$ the collections of all sets of the rank $\alpha$ form proper classes. And even if you would represent ordinals differently $V_\alpha$'s still would be proper classes in this model.

Comment: @Fedor ok, that seems fairly clear, but we can wait and see what Asaf comes up with.

Comment: @Asaf I don't even care about the image of the rank function being every well-order type, just that the domain is the universe, and only set-many sets have a rank at most a given value.

Comment: David, it's not about the image. It's about the possible ranks of your von Neumann ordinals. They cannot be exhausted before the you're done with the whole universe.

Comment: @Fedor: $\Pi_1$-Replacement is not a lot. A lot would be $\Sigma_3$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Personally I consider any collection/replacement principle stronger than $\Sigma_1$-Collection to be strong. We could develop most of basic set-theoretic constructions in $\mathsf{KP}$ and it could only prove $\Sigma_1$-Collection.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov: Why do you consider KP(P) to be strong? It does not have any replacement but simply has inbuilt power-set, which is arguably the correct way to axiomatize bounded ZF.

Comment: @user21820 I guess it is fundamentally matter of perspective. I am a proof-theorist and for me the main metrics is the proof-theoretic strength. And from this perspective unbounded applications of powerset are the core to the strength of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. So when you allow $\mathcal{P}$ as an atomic operation for me  the resulting theory $\mathsf{KP}(\mathcal{P})$ appears essentially as strong as $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself. And from the perspective of formalization of individual theorems, the only substantial limitation left is that $\mathsf{KP}(\mathcal{P})$ doesn't prove Mostowski collapsing.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov: I do not understand your perspective. Unbounded applications of Powerset contribute strength only if you have *other* strong assumptions such as impredicative Specification and Replacement. How can we 'blame' Powerset for that increase in strength if the real issue is with impredicativity? I know Powerset is not predicative, strictly speaking, but it's not as bad as unbounded quantification over the universe. Also, for you to use proof-theoretic strength as a gauge, you would need to state the p.t.o. of KP(P) and show that it is intrinsically comparable to that of ZFC...

Comment: @user21820 Consider as the base system the theory $\mathsf{BST}_0^{\mathsf{set}}$ axiomatized by Extensionality, totality of all Rudimentary recursive functions, and Infinity (see Definition VII.3.3 from Simpson's book on 2-nd order arithmetic). If you add to this theory Powerset, the resulting theory will be proof-theoretically equivalent to order $\omega$ arithmetic and would be able to prove the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathsf{Powerset}$ which is proof-theoretically equivalent to just second-order arithmetic and to $\mathsf{BST}_0^{\mathsf{set}}+\exists \mathcal{P}(\omega)$.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov: So? SOA (2nd-order arithmetic) is not that strong. Way way below ZFC. And SOA doesn't even have Powerset, so by your own criterion it shouldn't be considered strong. HOA (higher-order arithmetic) doesn't have unbounded Powerset either. So I really don't get your point.

Comment: @user21820 I was refuting your statement that Powerset doesn't contribute strength in isolation by pointing out that when compared with other axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ it provides more proof-theoretic strength (over weak base theory) than all of them combined. And by this substantiating my statement that Powerset is the core of proof-theoretic power of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov: You didn't refute a statement I didn't intend to make. I didn't mean it didn't contribute anything; I intended to say that impredicativity is critical to the strength of ZFC, not Powerset. Consider that ZFC without the underlying (classical) FOL rules cannot do anything, whereas ZFC−Powerset is as strong as SOA. You cannot by this infer that FOL contributes immense strength to ZFC compared to Powerset! To say in another way: Every system that can reach the strength of ZFC must have some impredicative reflection (e.g. unbounded Replacement).

Comment: To give you a concrete example, look at [this theory](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2021-September/022847.html), which has no Powerset but obviously has impredicative reflection.

Comment: @user21820 At this point I'll stop this conversation: Admittedly I have no taste in what seems to be going into a prolonged and fruitless argument on this very informal  (and ultimately fairly obscure in my opinion) topic.

Comment: Of course you can stop and leave at any point, especially if you cannot refute my points, even though they are simple and pertinent. It is completely well-known to experts that the proper strength scale for fragments of ZFC is the one given by Σ[n]-Rep[lacement], very like the proper strength scale for fragments of PA is the one given by Σ[n]-Ind[uction]. Your misconception about the strength of Powerset is because you're not looking at anything near the full strength of ZFC. Σ[n]-Rep is the n-th rung of the real ladder, while Powerset is on the floor below the 1st rung.

Comment: @useer21820 just chill, please. None of this is relevant to my question. I may delete all this debate as it shedding more heat than light.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

KP (Kripke-Platek set theory) is the most well-known fragment of $\sf{ZF}$ which suffices for the development of the rank function, thus $\sf{KPR}$ = $\sf{KP}$ + "for all ordinals $\alpha$,  $V(\alpha)$ exists" is the usual minimal theory in which one can be assured of the stratification of the universe into $V(\alpha)$s.

On the other hand, as observed by Mathias, $\sf{KPR}$ proves that Zermelo set theory $\sf{Z}$ has a transitive model, so in particular, $\sf{KPR}$ proves that $\sf{Z}$ is consistent; see Lemma 6.31 of [this preprint](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Eardm/maclane.pdf), which was later published in APAL (2001).

Therefore, by the second incompleteness theorem, even Zermelo set theory (let alone bounded Zermelo set theory) cannot interpret $\sf{KPR}$.

Finally, I will add that $\sf{KPR}$ is provable in the well-known extension $\sf{KP}^{\cal{P}}$ of $\sf{KP}$, which is also studied in Mathias' paper.

Comment: OK, cool. So it's probably $\sf{KP}^{\cal{P}}$ or Rathjen's $\sf{KP}(\cal{P})$ that I'm after, since I don't really want to give up power set right now. Or maybe $\sf{BZ}+\sf{KP}$...

Comment: But the theory $\sf Z + $$\forall \alpha : V_\alpha$ exists,  (where $\alpha$ is a von Neumann) will stratifiy the universe into stages, and this is weaker than $\sf KPR$?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar The two theories you mentioned are incomparable, the first has full separation but no collection, the second has some collection but not much separation.

Comment: @AliEnayat, Ah! Yes. But the point is why we need collection for? I mean take $\sf KP - collection + \forall x \exists \alpha: x \in V_\alpha$ , why that won't ensure stratifying the universe into $V(\alpha)'s$ ?

Answer (score 8):

One can directly assume in Zermelo that every set belongs to a rank.  This does not add any strength at all.  But notice that Zermelo may not prove the existence of very many von Neumann ordinals:  there may be well-orderings which do not have a von Neumann ordinal as order type.  A natural model of this theory is the union
of the V^{omega + n}'s for n a natural number.  Notice that in this structure the axioms of Zermelo hold, every object belongs to a V_alpha, but omega+omega does not exist.  There are well-orderings with order types far higher than omega+omega (and in this context the Scott representation of the ordinals is available).

There are a couple of additional remarks.  It is interesting to note
that the assertion that every set has a rank adds no strength at all to
Zermelo set theory (or to Zermelo set theory with bounded separation) but that adding this assertion to KP, a theory much weaker than Zermelo, gives a theory much stronger than Zermelo.  The reason is that KP has a lot of replacement.

The natural way to describe the rank function in "Zermelo with ranks" is probably to use the Scott ordinals as values of the rank function but note that the rank function is not necessarily onto the ordinals.  In the absence of replacement, the von Neumann notion of ordinal simply isn't the right notion of ordinal number.

Comment: Could you clarify what “adds no strength at all” means?

Comment: OK, this is nice. I'm not wedded to von Neumann ordinals, since ultimately what I want is something like Scott's trick, and I'm happy to get this from some class function from $V$ to a any old well-ordered class, where the preimage of every member is a set. But you are relying on Scott ordinals, and I haven't seen that before (at least, not outside ZF).

Comment: What do you mean by the Scott representation of the ordinals?  Is it something related to Scott's trick, e.g. represent a well-order-type by the set of all well-orderings of least rank having that order type?

Comment: @MikeShulman I assume so, but I don't know how to get this without having some kind of hierarchy as in question, which was the whole point! My only lead is section 3.6.1 in https://randall-holmes.github.io/proofsetslogic.pdf, where there are three extra axioms listed: Axiom of Ordinals, Axiom of Levels and Axiom of Rank. I presume that Randall in his answer is implying that one only needs the last of these, but in the notes the notion of rank uses _subhierarchies_, and it's not clearly signposted that these don't use the Ordinals and Levels axioms.

Comment: Aha, I see there is a second definition of rank, on page 275, in "Comments on the alternative definition". I think I see how Scott ordinals are a workable definition under the Axiom of Rank, though as Emil pointed out, why this "adds no strength at all" is unclear. (A claim of equiconsistency is made in https://randall-holmes.github.io/Drafts/hierarchy.pdf)

Comment: I've seen a citation to Matthias' "The strength of Mac Lane set theory" for the claim that adding an axiom of rank "adds no essential strength to Zermelo or Mac Lane set theory", but all I see are results about KP.